# .bind(this) gives old value and then updates new values

Tags: javascript, angular

The .bind(this) gives the old values first and then updates with the new value which is not the right way to bind every time it should give the fresh value.

Here is the parent component function ts

```js
this.openEdgeTokenSuccessCallback = this.openEdgeTokenSuccessCallback.bind(this);

openEdgeTokenSuccessCallback(reason) {
  console.log(response, 'value');
}
```

parent HTML

```html
<sc-ui-ezi-debit-card [onTokenSuccess]="openEdgeTokenSuccessCallback"></sc-ui-ezi-debit-card>
```

first, it gives 1 value and then 2 as value but I need this as 2 fresh values because 1 I have already used but when I again call the same function it gives first value 1 and then values 2

JS function

```js
export function SetupOpenEdgeEziDebit(tokenSuccessFunction) {
  secureEntryForm.onResult(tokenSuccessFunction);
}
```

child component ts :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.awaitOpenCardLessEdge();
}

private awaitOpenCardLessEdge(): void {
  // Call open edge to start loading in the iframes.
  SetupOpenEdgeEziDebit(this.onTokenSuccess);
  console.log(this.onTokenSuccess)
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little more? You don't need to bind openEdgeTokenSuccessCallback() because you are already calling the function with "this."

Comment: actually its a payment section where i am calling js function in another file and getting the value on this token success but along with that is taking old value and then running twice the function for for new update value

Comment: if i dnt bind to this then I cant access the other values outside the function hence I need to bind to access the values

Comment: Could you provide more code, Maybe some code from both the files which involve this function as it is still not clear

Comment: check now the function i have added

Comment: first, there is add button call on click an iframe opens and I enter the card details and then on submitting the opntokensuccessfun will call for iframe results

Comment: I am still not clear about the flow, But if you are trying to send a function to a child component.. you could try emitting an event from the child to the parent and run the function in the parent component itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238794/discussion-between-vinuta-and-adhi-narayan).